# How to set the user object to Sentry in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sentry

In a Spring Boot project I have a `SentryConfig.java` file

```java
    package example.services.bo.config;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver;

    @Configuration
    public class SentryConfig {
        @Bean
        public HandlerExceptionResolver sentryExceptionResolver() {
            return new io.sentry.spring.SentryExceptionResolver();
        }
    }
```

and a `sentry.properties` file:

```
dsn=http://123a98a06c844a85b34cdf0de1fcd114:abcc286fa2a846dcbc8334b3625bc7ac@sentry.example.com:9000/3
stacktrace.app.packages=example.services.bo
```

How I'll configure my Spring project to send user details to Sentry like, username and user id?

Edit:

```java
    @Configuration
    public class SentryConfig {
        @Bean
        public HandlerExceptionResolver sentryExceptionResolver() {
            Sentry.getContext().setUser(
                    new UserBuilder().setEmail("test@example.com").build()
            );
            return new io.sentry.spring.SentryExceptionResolver();
        }
    }
```

didn't help.

Comment: Are `username` and `user id` belongs to a servlet request?

Comment: You would have to set the user in the current context during a request cycle, not during bean initialization. Try that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the provided static methods by Sentry to set the user in the current context as seen in this [usage example](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/usage/#usage-example):

```java
        Sentry.getContext().setUser(
            new UserBuilder().setEmail("hello@sentry.io").build()
        );
```

Once an event occurs this will be also sent to Sentry as additional information.

Comment: How do you ensure the same user is changed across requests?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need the username or user id of the client, who's making API call. For example for Android userName could be the person who has logged in. If this is the case then you need to use `MDC` to push these details.  You need to initialize MDC at the Servlet filter or interceptor levels, it's up to you to use one of these. It's better to use the interceptor since you will have an option to clear the MDC context.

For any other additional details, you can use `sentry.properties` file. Read more about at https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/ 
for MDC context to work you need to set `mdctags`, in mdctags you can add all set of mdc tags you need. For example you would need `userName`, `userId` then add that as

```
mdctags=userName,userId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change exception-resolver-order of Sentry.

```
sentry.exception-resolver-order=2147483647
```

This setting will prevent Sentry from reporting exceptions handled in any other Spring exception handler.